# Cannot run Spark 1.2 on YARN

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm having trouble running a simple java app on YARN using spark 1.2.

When running:

```
spark-submit --class SQL --master yarn-client --executor-memory 2g
--executor-cores 1 target/learning-spark-mini-example-0.0.1.jar
```

I get this error:
http://pastebin.com/4VHDDunj

During the execution, `spark-assembly-1.2.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar` is transmitted over the network, which takes a very long time.
Seems weird, why upload such a big file? Shouldn't it already be on the cluster?

Here is the configuration I'm using: 
http://pastebin.com/qVsC5qdM.

It should be noted that no username or password is anywhere specified.
It's not clear to me where I should set them.
Spark tries to use my local "lorenzo" username on the cluster (where it also exists).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How about posting the actual code?

Comment: Have you tried running one of the provided example apps before running your own code, just to check whether the problem is in the configuration?

Comment: I've not yet run the example code. the code is doing nothing...here it is though http://pastebin.com/XaxGhBV8 I'm king of sure it's a configuration error.

Comment: There are other possible causes, other than app. code and configuration. E.g. running out of disk space, bug in the underlying software and similar stuff.

Answer (score 0):

That may well end up being the `NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/service/CompositeService` that others also reported.

To exclude, take a look [here](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/46/noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoop-service-compositeservice-shell-exitcodeexception-classnotfoundexception).

Comment: I use linux so that is not the case.
Anyways, I tried running spark-submit from within the cluster and it works.

Comment: I thought that the error does not happen only on Win, my bad.